# Oracle 11g Auditing Capabilities

Tags: security, oracle11g, hipaa

We have sensitive data in our database and I wanted to look into Oracle auditing capabilities. Our install is Embedded since it came with the application we have. Any feedback is appreaciated.

Comment: Are you asking what is technically possible?  Or what your license allows?  If you really have an embedded license, you would generally only be able to interact with the database via the application so your license would limit you to whatever capabilities the application allows you to configure and use.  If you are asking about technical capabilities, what specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: More specifically: 1) Is there any way to do auditing with embedded license? Even with 3rd party software? 2) If not, what version of Oracle would I need? WHat additional licensing would I need? Is there a 3rd party application that can do this? THansk!

Comment: If the database is truly using an embedded license, the features that are available would be driven by the application.  If the application allows you to configure and manage auditing, you can use it.  Otherwise, you can't.  You'd need a full database license if you want to be able to interact with the database using something other than the third-party application.

Comment: Of course, as with all licensing questions, you really want to talk with the application vendor/ Oracle sales rather than relying on some guy on the internet.  Licenses are complex and often-customized contracts so general advice often falls short.